# awk to print nth instance of string

Tags: awk

I have a reasonably large .dat file and I want to use an awk script to print the 2nd occurrence of a string.
.dat file:

```
YCSB Client 0.1
Command line: -db com.yahoo.ycsb.db.MongoDbClient -s -P /home/james/YCSB/workloads/workloada -p mongodb.url=mongodb://192.168.0.8:27017 -p mongodb.database=ycsb -p recordcount=105 -t
new database url = 192.168.0.8:27017/ycsb
mongo connection created with 192.168.0.8:27017/ycsb
[OVERALL], RunTime(ms), 1086.0
[OVERALL], Throughput(ops/sec), 920.8103130755064
[UPDATE], Operations, 506
[UPDATE], AverageLatency(us), 988.4288537549407
[UPDATE], MinLatency(us), 410
[UPDATE], MaxLatency(us), 43786
[UPDATE], 95thPercentileLatency(ms), 2
[UPDATE], 99thPercentileLatency(ms), 6
[UPDATE], Return=1, 506
[UPDATE], 0, 432
[UPDATE], 1, 40
[UPDATE], 2, 9
[UPDATE], 3, 9
[UPDATE], 4, 4
[UPDATE], 5, 6
```

...

```
[UPDATE], 997, 0
[UPDATE], 998, 0
[UPDATE], 999, 0
[UPDATE], >1000, 0
[READ], Operations, 494
[READ], AverageLatency(us), 429.2004048582996
[READ], MinLatency(us), 177
[READ], MaxLatency(us), 9428
[READ], 95thPercentileLatency(ms), 1
[READ], 99thPercentileLatency(ms), 5
[READ], Return=1, 494
[READ], 0, 460
[READ], 1, 16
[READ], 2, 6
[READ], 3, 3
[READ], 4, 4
```

...

```
[READ], 995, 0
[READ], 996, 0
[READ], 997, 0
[READ], 998, 0
[READ], 999, 0
[READ], >1000, 0
[CLEANUP], Operations, 1
[CLEANUP], AverageLatency(us), 1397.0
[CLEANUP], MinLatency(us), 1397
[CLEANUP], MaxLatency(us), 1397
[CLEANUP], 95thPercentileLatency(ms), 1
[CLEANUP], 99thPercentileLatency(ms), 1
```

I have been using this command to attempt to print the second occurrence of `AverageLatency` and `Operations`:

```
awk -F'[,=]|://' '/^Command/{db=$2}/AverageLatency/{i=$3}/Operations/{t=$3}END{print t i,db}'
```

However it seems to be returning values from the bottom of the file or the 3rd occurrence:

```
1 1397.0 mongodb
```

I am relatively new to using awk but it seems as though it works from the bottom of the file upwards?

I have tried using `awk /AverageLatency/{i++}i==2` in my command as it works on its own and returns the correct values.

Just for clarity the desired output here would be `494 429.2004048582996 mongodb`

Comment: it keeps reading thru the file til it gets to the end, matching each time it finds `AverageLatency`, so it printing values from the last time. To see what I mean, do `/AverageLatency/{i=$3;exit}END{...` Good luck

Comment: Yes! awk -F'[,=]|://' '/^Command/{db=$2}/AverageLatency/{i++}i==2{i=$3;exit}/Operations/{t=$3}END{print t i,db}'
Works perfectly.

Comment: feel free to post your own answer and accept after 48 hrs for 15 points of reputation. Welcome to S.O. Good luck.

Comment: To get second hit, do: `awk '/AverageLatency/ && ++i==2' file `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
awk -F'[=:]|, ' '/^Command/{db=$3} /Operations/ && ++i==2 {f=1;t=$NF} /AverageLatency/ && f {print t,$NF,db;exit}' file
494 429.2004048582996 mongodb
```

When second `Operations` is found get its data and set flag `f`
If flag `f` is true and `AverageLatency` print the data

If order of pattern to find is not know, and you just like to get second data out of them:

```
awk -F'[=:]|, ' '/^Command/{db=$3} /Operations/ && ++i==2 {f=1;t=$NF} /AverageLatency/ && ++j==2 {a=$NF} END {print t,a,db}' file
494 429.2004048582996 mongodb
```

---

If `AverageLatency` always comes after `Operations`, just grab next line.

```
awk -F'[=:]|, ' '/^Command/{db=$3} /Operations/ && ++i==2 {f=NR;t=$NF} NR==f+1 && f {print t,$NF,db;exit}' file
494 429.2004048582996 mongodb
```

Or you can use `getline` but be careful with it.

```
awk -F'[=:]|, ' '/^Command/{db=$3} /Operations/ && ++i==2 {t=$NF;getline;print t,$NF,db;exit}' file
494 429.2004048582996 mongodb
```

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F'[,=]|://' '/^Command/{db=$2}/AverageLatency/{i++}i==2{i=$3;exit}/Operations/{t=$3}END{prin‌​t t i,db}'
```

Works perfectly. The script I was using was continuing to look through the entire file even after it had matched the string I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Use an if statement and a counter.  The END{} block runs at the end of processing all of the input.  So it will only print out the last values matched with your implementation.

```
awk -F'[,=]|://' 'BEGIN{i=0} /^Command/{db=$2}/AverageLatency/{if(2 == ++i){ print t $3,db; exit; } }/Operations/{t=$3}'
```